# Why is Rocket League the only application that doesn't open with the python subprocess library?

Tags: python, subprocess

this is the code that I wrote:

```
import subprocess

rocket_league_path = 'D:\rocketleague\Binaries\Win64\RocketLeague.exe'
subprocess.Popen(rocket_league_path)
```

this is the error it shows to me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Marco\Desktop\Untitled-1.py", line 7, in <module>
    subprocess.Popen(rocket_league_path)
  File "C:\Users\Marco\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 966, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\Marco\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 1435, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Cannot find the specified file
```

I have tried with other applications and it works with all except Rocket League

Comment: `\r` is an escape sequence.

Comment: Use a [raw string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-prefixes-do-and-what-are-raw-string-literals).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a quirk of the way string literals work in Python.  The `\` character is special, it indicates that the following characters may be interpreted as a special character.  Or it may not, depending on what follows.  In your case the two characters `\r` are being converted to a single character Carriage Return.  The path is now incomplete and the file can't be found.  If it had been `\c` instead it would have worked, because there's no special character corresponding to `\c`.

You can easily fix it by using a raw character string instead, where the `\` loses its special meaning.

```
rocket_league_path = r'D:\rocketleague\Binaries\Win64\RocketLeague.exe'
#                    ^
```